# Map tRestClient input with its output in Talend

Tags: talend

Is it possible to map the input of a tRestClient to its ouput ? I would like reuse row fields of the request with the row fields of the result and mix them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tReplicate to get o copy of the input flow, tHashOutput and tHashInput to store and retrieve the responce of the tRestClient:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done something like that. But my problem is that i have not realy something to make a strong mapping in my restresponse.

Comment: Responce will be in json format, so u have to extract fields using `tExtractJSONFields` before store responce into `tHashOutput`